# Angular 2 - binding input form data to SVG text element

Tags: svg, angular

I'm looking to bind a form input string to an svg text element in an Angular 2 template.  I'm not sure how to do this and would appreciate any help.

```
 <svg class="box">
          <rect class="largeFrame" x="40" y="10" rx="10" ry="10"/>
          <text class="name" x ="400" y="40">Name</text>
          <text class="personName" x="400" y="55" [textContent]="personName.value"></text>
       </svg>  
        <form #f="ngForm">
        <div class="input">
            <label for="name">Enter Your Name</label>
            <input  type="text" [(ngModel)]="personName.value" id="name">
        </div>
```

[textContent] is not working... can anyone clue me in on the best syntax?  Or suggest a method for binding SVG and inputs in Angular 2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I needed to use [()] to bind the data.
I also needed to give personName.value an initial value.

```
<text class="personName" x="400" y="55" [(textContent)]="personName.value"></text>
```

Answer (score 0):

- use interpolation binding, which will bind to the `textContent` property for you
- use the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator) to guard against `null` and `undefined`, then you won't need to specify an initial value

```
<text class="personName" x="400" y="55">{{personName?.value}}</text>
```